# How can use println java in android?

Tags: java, android, textview, println

How can use println java in android ?

I want to use println java in android **textview**
need a tetxview autobricker in loop

```
public class p_00 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rd = new Random();
        rd.nextInt(101);
        int hesam , hadi;
        for(hesam = rd.nextInt(101) , hadi=rd.nextInt(101)
                ; hesam  <=1000 || hadi <=1000;
                   hesam+=rd.nextInt(11) , hadi+=rd.nextInt(11)){
            System.out.println("Hesam number is " + hesam+
                    "Hadi number is "+ hadi);
        }
        if(hesam > hadi){
            System.out.println("Hesam Won "+ hesam);
        }else if(hesam < hadi){
            System.out.println("Hadi Won "+ hadi);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Both Win :) +");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Log.i(String tag, String message)`

Comment: ty for ansawer but i need show to mobile

Comment: Man, you can edit your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: use the [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class in Android.

Answer (score 1):

like any other java application

```
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

**but it would be better if you use the logger**... in android is called LogCat...

```
Log.i(String tag, String msg);
```

## Edit:

textview  is a widget element  and as such has its own  [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType))  for setting the text in...